# Remote Access Management Console missing on Server 2012

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012, remote-access

I have Windows Server 2012 and I have installed all the Remote Access roles and features.

When I try to get into Remote Access Management Console by searching it in the search, I can't find it. [According to Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574177.aspx), there should be such an application.

[image]

How do I find it?

Comment: Have you looked in Administrative Tools or Server Manager?

Comment: @joeqwerty In Server Manager I only see the logs and can't configure. In Administrative tools there's no such entry.